# How to Send CSV file Generated by PhpExcel to Ftp Server Without Saving

Tags: php, csv, ftp, phpexcel, export-to-csv

I am generating CSV File using phpexcel and i am able to download and save the csv file but i am unable to upload csv file generated by phpexcel to ftp server directly without saving please guide me to upload csv file generated by phpexcel without saving locally my code is below

```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   include 'PHPExcel.php';
   include PHPExcel/Writer/CSV.php';
   require_once "PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";
   $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);  
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1',"1");
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1',"2"); 
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A2',"3"); 

   $filename='gs.csv'; //just some random filename
   header('Content-Type: text/CSV');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
   header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
   $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV'); 
   $objWriter->save('php://output');

   $ftp_server='ftp.exc.in'; 
   $ftp_user_name='user'; 
   $ftp_user_pass='pass';

   $local_file=fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
   $remote_file="/test/gs.csv";
   rewind($local_file);

   $ftp_conn=ftp_connect($ftp_server); 

   @$login_result=ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 


   if($login_result) $upload_result=ftp_fput($ftp_conn, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_ASCII);

   ftp_close($ftp_conn);

   fclose($local_file);
```

The above code generate the csv file but it is asking to download but i need only upload the csv file without saving locally

Comment: Remove the header statements in your code and save it in a temporary file on the server before you FTP it.

Comment: i removed header content but not working

Comment: And did you also modify your code to save the file on the server before you FTP it?

Comment: I want to upload csv file without storing the file

Comment: I modified the code but not working

Comment: can you share the modified code

Comment: is there any way to upload csv file without store as a temporary file

Comment: There might be but why the aversion to saving it temporarily on the server?

Comment: I am sending csv file for one minute once so creating temporary file will create issue like delay and memory issue so i am try to avoid creating temporary file